# symmetric positive definite matrices

Tags: matrices, differential-geometry

Why must a symmetric positive definite matrix must be invertible? I'm reading a proof of the Levi-Civita theorem in differential geometry but the author states this without proof and I haven't been able to prove it.

Comment: Because its null space is trivial.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose a positive definite matrix $P$ were not invertible.  Then there would be a nonzero vector $x$ such that $Px = 0$.  Multiplying both sides of this equation on the left by $x^T$ gives $x^TPx = x^T0 = 0$ for $x\neq 0$, contradicting positive definiteness.

Comment: Short and sweet.

Comment: Precisely. This is a great solution. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Symmetric matrices are diagonalizable:
$$ S = U D U^T$$
for $U^T = U^{-1}$ and $D$ a diagonal matrix whose entries are the eigenvalues.  When $S$ is positive definite, all the eigenvalues must be strictly positive.  Hence if $D = \text{diag}(d_1,\dotsc,d_n)$ then $D$ is invertible with $D^{-1} = \text{diag}(d_1^{-1},\dotsc,d_n^{-1})$.  Then one may check that $S^{-1} = U D^{-1} U^T$, and in particular $S$ is invertible.

Answer (score 0):

Symmetric matrices are diagonalizable,and diagonal entries are real. if it's positive definite,then 
all the eigenvalues must be strictly positive.And similar matrices have the same eigenvalues. so,it's invertible.